# Form submit event problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return CheckForm(this)">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function CheckForm(frm)
            {
               if(CheckEntireForm(frm) == false)
               return false;   
            } 
    </script>
```

Hello EveryBody Please help me to get solution

I've used a javascript function on form's onSubmit event like

which validates my page's textboxes etc.
NOTE: i am not using asp.net's validation. i have got my own validation classes

I've also used a dropdownlist with auto post back set to true

in asp.net 2.0 when dropdownlist's selected index is changed it

calls form's onsubmit while this did not use to happen in asp.net 1.1

I've used this on 140 pages in my website the worst case will be to call

CheckForm(this.form) on my save buttons client click on all the pages.

I am looking for a backword compatibility solution which can be applied at a single place

like web.config or some class etc.
i am using asp.net and javascript

Comment: you haven't stated what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You have forget to return the **true** - your form never submit.